# css/bootstrap : overflow issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a display issue with the popover control. I had to set the overflow property to 'visible' otherwise it would be hidden behind the table.

```
  overflow:visible;
```

See jsfiddle for repro :  http://jsfiddle.net/vEMrD/

But now that I've set it to visible, the table has display issues related to the horizontal scrollbar. In the jsfiddle, just change the css property overflow to 'hidden' and the table will look just fine, however the popover is then hidden (click 'display filter' to reproduce)

anyone knows what's wrong with the css ?

Comment: put `overflow:visible` in  .gridStyle and remove from .ngHeaderContainer the scroll bar which comes because of fixed width and your contents are too big than width moreover sam  i can't able to understand your need.. :P

Comment: @VivekVikranth, I've done that but if you resize your browser to a smaller size, the scrollbar will still appear and the display problem occurs again. I've only set the width to a fixed size so I could show you the problem more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `data-container="body"` to the popover link. Try http://jsfiddle.net/vEMrD/5/ for a working example. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage - and in specific the container flag - on how to break out the popover from its default container. `body` works, but you can be more specific if necessary.

Comment: That's great Sean ! Thanks a lot for fixing it !